# How do I pass a view through a parameter?

Tags: view, parameters, colors, background

So basically I want to get a button to change color, but I won't be pressing this button, it is an idle button. Other buttons are supposed to change this by clicking them.

I want to pass the view into a parameter and then use that view to change the backgrounds color.

```
     changeColorBlack(R.id.light);
```

this is the line I have in mind on how to pass it, but it keeps saying it is an int and cannot be passed. Is there another way to do this, or even a picture that is easily changed from color to color with out having to worry about making it a useable view in the class?

Comment: Knowing the language, OS, and Framework you are using would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
create function p1() returns INTEGER DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return @p1;
create view h_parm as select * from sw_hardware_big where unit_id = p1() ;
```

Then you can call a view with a parameter:

```
select s.* from (select @p1:=12 p) parm , h_parm s;
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question? This does not read very well.